# NLP with Python - how to build a corpus, which classifier to use?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

I’m trying to figure out which direction to take my Python NLP project in, and I’d be very grateful to the SO community for any advice.

**Problem:**

Let’s say I have 100 .txt files that contain the minutes of 100 meetings held by a decisionmaking body. I also have 100 .txt files of corresponding meeting outcomes, which contain the resolutions passed by this body. The outcomes fall into one of seven categories – 1 – take no action, 2 – take soft action, 3 – take stronger action, 4 – take strongest action, 5 – cancel soft action previously taken, 6 – cancel stronger action previously taken, 7 – cancel strongest action previously taken. Alternatively, this can be presented on a scale from -3 to +3, with 0 signifying no action, +1 signifying soft action, -1 signifying cancellation of soft action previously taken, and so on.

**Based on the text of the inputs, I’m interested in predicting which of these seven outcomes will occur.**

I’m thinking of treating this as a form of sentiment analysis, since the decision to take a certain kind of action is basically a sentiment. However, all the sentiment analysis examples I’ve found have focused on positive/negative dichotomies, sometimes adding in neutral sentiment as a category. I haven’t found any examples with more than 3 possible classifications of outcomes – not sure whether this is because I haven’t looked in the right places, because it just isn’t really an approach of interest for whatever reason, or because this approach is a silly idea for some reason of which I’m not yet quite sure.

**Question 1.** Should be I approaching this as a form of sentiment analysis, or is there some other approach that would work better? Should I instead treat this as a kind of categorization matter, similar to classifying news articles by topic and training the model to recognize the "topic" (outcome)?

**Corpus:**

I understand that I will need to build a corpus for training/test data, and it looks like I have two immediately evident options:

1 – hand-code a CSV file for training data that would contain some key phrases from each input text and list the value of the corresponding outcome on a 7-point scale, similar to what’s been done here: http://help.sentiment140.com/for-students

2 – use the approach Pang and Lee used (http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/) and put each of my .txt files of inputs into one of seven folders based on outcomes, since the outcomes (what kind of action was taken) are known based on historical data.

The downside to the first option is that it would be very subjective – I would determine which keywords/phrases I think are the most important to include, and I may not necessarily be the best arbiter. The downside to the second option is that it might have less predictive power because the texts are pretty long, contain lots of extraneous words/phrases, and are often stylistically similar (policy speeches tend to use policy words). I looked at Pang and Lee’s data, though, and it seems like that may not be a huge problem, since the reviews they’re using are also not very varied in terms of style. I’m leaning towards the Pang and Lee approach, but I’m not sure if it would even work with more than two types of outcomes.

**Question 2.** Am I correct in assuming that these are my two general options for building the corpus? Am I missing some other (better) option?

**Question 3.** Given all of the above, which classifier should I be using? I’m thinking maximum entropy would work best; I’ve also looked into random forests, but I have no experience with the latter and really have no idea what I’m doing (yet) when it comes to them.

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: Many of such answers would depend on the type of data as for any ML solution. Can you post some sample data? You might want to go through the actual text once then depending on that you can hand code the features. For example I feel that length of the meeting discussion can be one feature, no action might have smaller discussion than other strong decisions. You can definitely remove high frequency words and use the bag of words features also. Manually selecting phrases seems a not so good option to me. Also you might wanna mention what's the amount of data you have got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 - The most straightforward way to think of this is as a text classification task (sentiment analysis is one kind of text classification task, but by no means the only one).

Alternatively, as you point out, you could consider your data as existing on a continuum ranging from -3 (cancel strongest action previously taken) to +3 (take strongest action), with 0 (take no action) in the middle. In this case you could treat the outcome as a continuous variable with a natural ordering. If so, then you could treat this as a regression problem rather than a classification problem. It's hard to know whether this is a sensible thing to do without knowing more about the data. If you suspect you will have a number of words/phrases that will be very probable at one end of the scale (-3) and very improbable at the other (+3), or vice versa, then regression may make sense. On the other hand, if the relevant words/phrases are associated with strong emotion and are likely to appear at either end of the scale but not in the middle, then you may be better off treating it as classification. It also depends on how you want to evaluate your results. If your algorithm predicts that a document is a -2 and it's actually a -3, will it be penalized less than if it had predicted +3? If so, it might be better to treat this as a regression task.

Question 2. "Am I correct in assuming that these are my two general options for building the corpus? Am I missing some other (better) option?"

Note that the set of documents (the .txt files of meeting minutes and corresponding outcomes) is your corpus -- the typical thing to do is randomly select 20% or so to be set aside as test data and use the remaining 80% as training data. The two general options you consider above are options for selecting the set of features that your classification or regression algorithm should attend to.

You correctly identify the upsides and downsides of the two most obvious approaches for coming up with features (hand-picking your own vs. Pang & Lee's approach of just using unigrams (words) as phrases).

Personally I'd also lean towards this latter approach, given that it's notoriously hard for humans to predict which phrases will be useful for classification--although there's no reason why you couldn't combine the two, having your initial set of features include all words plus whatever phrases you think might be particularly relevant. As you point out, there will be a lot of extraneous words, so it may help to throw out words that are very infrequent, or that don't differ enough in frequency between classes to provide any discriminative power. Approaches for reducing an initial set of features are known as "feature selection" techniques - one common method is mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25524/feature-selection-for-the-text-mining). Or see [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.32.9956&rep=rep1&type=pdf) for a more comprehensive list.

You could also consider features like the percent of high-valence words, high-arousal words, or high-dominance words, using the dataset [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758/s13428-012-0314-x) (click Supplementary Material and download the zip).

Depending on how much effort you want to put into this project, another common thing to do is to try a whole bunch of approaches and see which works best. Of course, you can't test which approach works best using data in the test set--that would be cheating and would run the risk of overfitting to the test data. But you can set aside a small part of your training set as 'validation data' (i.e. a mini-test set that you use for testing different approaches). Given that you don't have that much training data (80 documents or so), you could consider using [cross validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)).

Question 3 - The best way is probably to try different approaches and pick whatever works best in cross-validation. But if I had to pick one or two, I personally have found that [k-nearest neighbor classification (with low k) or SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/supervised_learning.html) often work well for this kind of thing. A reasonable approach might be

- having your initial features be all unigrams (words) + phrases that
  you think might be predictive after you look at some training data;
- applying a feature selection technique to trim down your feature set;
- applying any
  algorithm that can deal with high-dimensional/text features, such as those in http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2475/ir10/forelasningar/Lecture9_4.pdf (lots of good tips in that pdf!), or those that achieved decent performance in the Pang & Lee paper.

Other possibilities are discussed in http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/13bayes.pdf . Often the specific algorithm matters less than the features that go into it. Frankly it sounds like a very difficult sort of classification task, so it's possible that nothing will work very well.

If you decide to treat it as a regression rather than a classification task, you could go with k nearest neighbors regression ( http://www.saedsayad.com/k_nearest_neighbors_reg.htm ) or ridge regression.

Random forests often do not work well with large numbers of dependent features (words), though they may work well if you end up deciding to go with a smaller number of features (for example, a set of words/phrases you manually select, plus % of high-valence words and % of high-arousal words).

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot to mention that SVMs and some other approaches perform best when there is an approximately equal number of training samples of each class. If this is not the case, you might consider oversampling the data from the smaller classes, or using an approach that is not sensitive to these imbalances.